# How to store CSV data into variables?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to store data from a CSV file in python variables:

I have this CSV:

```
CountryName,  ChargeMinutes
Cape Verde ,    0.00
Algeria ,       10.80
St. Lucia ,     0.00
Cameroon ,      48.75
United States , 457,929.00
```

And I need to create a variable for each country and assign it with the same name and add the actually charge minutes, for example:

```
cape_verde = 0
algeria = 10
st_lucia = 0
cameroon = 48 
etc...
```

I already have the output from the CSV, but I can't figure out how to store the data output in variables.

```
import csv

with open("datatmx_headers.csv", "r") as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        country = row['CountryName']
        minutes = row['ChargeMinutes']
        print(country, minutes)
```

Comment: Like you already save it all in variables :D

Comment: What do you mean by storing as a python variables ? You mean real python variables ? Or all what you want is applying some logic to your data ?

Comment: I need to store it in variables for then compare with others , I want to set thresholds in base those variables

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a dictionary and use it as a list of variable. This way you can store and track all of your variables info in one place.

```
var = {}
with open("datatmx_headers.csv", "r") as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        var[row['CountryName']] = row['ChargeMinutes']
```

[image]

I hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So a few things you need to do before reaching the proposed goal.
Since you have special cases like "Cape Verde ", "St. Lucia", "Algeria ".

To handle "Cape Verde " and "Algeria " that have whitespaces at the end of string you should add:

```
for row in csv_input:
    country = row['CountryName'.strip()]
    minutes = row['ChargeMinutes']
    print(country, minutes)
```

Now you won't find Country Names with whitespaces at the end. Then we should handle names that contain "."

```
for row in csv_input:
    country = row['CountryName'.strip().replace(".","")]
    minutes = row['ChargeMinutes']
    print(country, minutes)
```

Finally, we should remove white spaces between two word names like "Cape Verde" and replace it with "_".

```
for row in csv_input:
    country = row['CountryName'.strip().replace(".","").replace(" ","_")]
    minutes = row['ChargeMinutes']
    print(country, minutes)
```

And instead of having a variable for each country I suggest you to add all of them to a dictionary to have them in a single variable and easily access the data.

```
my_dict = {}
for row in csv_input:
    country = row['CountryName'.strip().replace(".","").replace(" ","_")]
    minutes = row['ChargeMinutes']
    my_dict[country] = minutes
```

After this you should be able to access data like this:

```
print(my_dict.algeria) #prints 10.80
print(my_dict.Cape_Verde) #prints 0.0
```